# Axios Post Error Error: Cannot POST /api/v1/upload

Tags: node.js, axios

I am posting to my API using Axios but I get the error
`<pre>Cannot POST /api/v1/upload</pre>\n`

This appears as quite strange it says 404- That error is pretty obvious right? I know that error is obvious so I double checked the link, but it still says 404. Here is a snippet of my API Code: `Router.post("/upload", async (req, res) => { const { token, userid, id, type, prefix, _, maker, owner, statustxt, statustype, ownerId } = req.body;`

Has anyone had this error and if so can you suggest what to do?

I have attempted to troubleshoot it by replacing the URL but it still shows the error 404.

More Information on the
error: `<pre>Cannot POST /api/v1/upload</pre>\n` 
Here is a snippet of my API:
 `Router.get("/upload", async (req, res) => { const { token, userid, id, type, prefix, _, maker, owner, statustxt, statustype, ownerId } = req.body;`

Comment: it would be more easier if you provide how you send request to the backend

Comment: Hi, please read [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

its obvious you are setting a `GET` endpoint and sending a `POST` request as your code shows as below

```
Router.get("/upload", async (req, res) => { const { token, userid, id, type, prefix, _, maker, owner, statustxt, statustype, ownerId } = req.body;
```

either you have to update the route accordingly as below

```
Router.post("/upload", async (req, res) => { const { token, userid, id, type, prefix, _, maker, owner, statustxt, statustype, ownerId } = req.body;
```

or change the requesting method from `POST` to `GET`

Comment: it whould be esier if you provide updated code

Comment: Updated Code:
API: https://sourceb.in/7oKGVEreyX
Main:  https://sourceb.in/UhLmnRCGb4
As you can see I post with Axios to my API But it still says 404 when the endpoint is correct also it would be /api/v1/ as In my index I set it to that and it works.